# JQuery 'files' property throwing error in visual studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2012

I have added the following code in my javascript file.

```
$('#file0')[0].files[0].size
```

file0 is a file upload control.

after adding the above code, I am getting compilation error stating.

> The property 'files' does not exist on value of type 'HTMLElement'.

But the code seems to be valid code and it works.

Please help me to resolve the compilation error.

Comment: I'm sure there's an option to turn that off, and/or an update you can load. I'm surprised it's anything but a warning in the first place, frankly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is not a warning. it is an error.

Comment: you want the size of file?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: No, he wants Visual Studio to stop bothering him about something that isn't an error.

Comment: @ElegantCoder: I didn't say it wasn't, I said that surprised me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  ow sorry for my wrong answer i had deleted that

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it a  Typescript Error?

Comment: I found that there is a JQuery.d.ts file which has all the extensions. Is there any way I can add files property into it?

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an `HTMLInputElement` before calling the `.files` property, like so:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>$('#file0')[0]).files[0].size
```